# Making drugs out of human excrement?

Tags: trade

So, in my post apocalyptic world, drugs are sold pretty much everywhere, except Midwest Empire. People have been experimenting with new ways to get wrecked and have a good time.

Enter in a man named Jen. He wants to get into the market quickly, but growing traditional “ingredients” like coca leaves and opium poppies would take a long time, or at least too long for Jen’s impatience. He is a bit of a tinkerer, graduating from the university of New Jerusalem, and so decides to use a common resource: the human excrement out of his towns cesspit. He wants to use it to make some drugs.

It doesn’t really matter how it works, so my question is: could human excrement be turned into a drug?

Comment: Sure.  For example B12 is only created by bacteria in the intestine.  So vegetarian animals either partially digest and then re-injest their food (like cows) or eat their own feces.  You can get B12 out of feces. https://plenteousveg.com/b12-intestinal-bacteria/

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - more "drug" like and less "supplement like" would be growing mushrooms in the poo.  *psylocybin cubensis* grows in cow poop (avoid angry bulls and farmers when picking) so it would be a simple matter of instead harvesting poo from feedlots/slaughter house holding pens OR finding a 'shroom (or handwaving it) that grows in human poo instead of (as well as?) cow poo.  FWIW most "domestic" growing of *p. cubensis* is done on a rice medium.

Comment: Well... if [Tommy Chong can get high smoking a cockroach](https://youtu.be/z08zZ1xW9Yw?t=45s), then why not human excrement?  On the downside, excrement is a function of what you ate, which means its chemical makeup will vary wildly, potentially making a predictable narcotic difficult and unbelievable.

Comment: A partial answer might be found in the fact that drugs and metabolites of drugs in our feces and urine pass through conventional water treatment and are released into the environment, mostly becoming estrogen like compounds which interfere with the reproductive cycles of fish.

Comment: New sources of drugs are really a real life problems. Only possible answer is **"if it could, it would be already"**

Comment: It could be used to grow magic mushrooms.

Comment: Are you trolling us or is your name choice coincidentally see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkem

Comment: @Silent-Bob: I wasn’t trolling that was a coincidence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkem) feces can and have beed used to make drugs:

> Jenkem is an inhalant and hallucinogen created from fermented human waste. In the mid-1990s, it was reported to be a popular street drug among Zambian street children. They would put the feces and urine in a jar and cover it with a balloon then let it ferment out in the sun, then afterwards they would inhale the fumes created.

The name of your fictional drug-baron seems appropriate in comparison to the real-world drug ;)

To make it work in your setting, Jen would need to find a way to distribute the gas (maybe he has access to a shipment of balloons or condoms) and hide the fact, that everybody could make the drug themselves. Maybe he finds a secret way to make it smell better, so it has more recreational value than the street version.

Answer (score 1):

This does exist in the form of an inhalant and haluxigenic known as [jenkem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkem), credit to silent-bob for pointing this disgusting fact out.

It is created with fermented human waste, in Zambia where it was inverted street kids would fill a jar, put a balloon over the top as a lid, stick the jar in the sun and wait for it to fill,  then inhale the gasses produce